# How to break word to the next line with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make it look better for mobile: 
(break words by line)

I tried white-space, word-break, word-spacing, display:table-caption and can't make it work.

https://codepen.io/Jackkk/pen/zYYbvKY

```css
.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* very simplified css*/
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-line-bottom nav-normal nav-size-normal nav-center">
  <li class="tab active has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-fryzjerskie"><span>Meble fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_fotele-fryzjerskie"><span>Fotele fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_myjnie-fryzjerskie"><span>Myjnie fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_konsolety-fryzjerskie"><span>Konsolety fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_pomocniki-fryzjerskie"><span>Pomocniki fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-48h"><span>Meble 48h</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Link to example website: https://dobrzekupuj.pl/

[image]

Comment: Image how it could look: https://dobrzekupuj.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/oldnew.jpg

Comment: Please do not try to bypass the restrictions SO placed on you. Post code HERE and image HERE

Comment: Consider using a framework. It is hard to make a site look good on all devices and all browsers. Depending on the underlying workflow: Bootstrap, Material-UI, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `width` or `max-width` to every `li`

For example

```
.nav > li {
    width: 70px;
}
```

or

```
.nav > li {
    max-width: 70px;
}
```

For mobile only put it on a media query

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav > li {
        width: 70px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav > li {
        width: 70px;
    }
}

but the first item in second row (on mobile) is few pixels shifted to the right https://dobrzekupuj.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/1111111.png

Comment: This is because the last item has 0 margin on the right as you can see with inspect tool. Put inside the media query this .nav.nav-normal li:last-child {margin-right: 7px;!important} to override the css.

Answer (score 0):

the `table-layout` set to `fixed` seems the best option to wrap all elements at once into 2 lines :

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  border-spacing: 1vw 0;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* makup/see me */
li {border:1px solid;}
ul {
  border-spacing: 1vw 0;
}
* {margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-line-bottom nav-normal nav-size-normal nav-center">
  <li class="tab active has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-fryzjerskie"><span>Meble fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_fotele-fryzjerskie"><span>Fotele fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_myjnie-fryzjerskie"><span>Myjnie fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_konsolety-fryzjerskie"><span>Konsolety fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_pomocniki-fryzjerskie"><span>Pomocniki fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-48h"><span>Meble 48h</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

to keep it always shrink to minimun, again the `table-layout` (not set to `fixed` here ) seems to be the best option :

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  width:0;/* will shrink/expand to fit content anyway */
  margin: auto;
  border-spacing: 1vw 0;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* makup/see me */
li {border:1px solid;}
ul {
  border-spacing: 1vw 0;
}
* {margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-line-bottom nav-normal nav-size-normal nav-center">
  <li class="tab active has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-fryzjerskie"><span>Meble fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_fotele-fryzjerskie"><span>Fotele fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_myjnie-fryzjerskie"><span>Myjnie fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_konsolety-fryzjerskie"><span>Konsolety fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_pomocniki-fryzjerskie"><span>Pomocniki fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-48h"><span>Meble 48h</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Run both snippets in full page to see different behavior.

Note also, that some padding on your original code could also work to set your wrapping point earlier

---

from your update on codepen, the table-layout can be used only on li too.

```css
.nav>li {
  display: inline-table;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav>li {
    width: 0;
    border: solid;
  }
}


/* very simplified css*/
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-line-bottom nav-normal nav-size-normal nav-center">
  <li class="tab active has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-fryzjerskie"><span>Meble fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_fotele-fryzjerskie"><span>Fotele fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_myjnie-fryzjerskie"><span>Myjnie fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_konsolety-fryzjerskie"><span>Konsolety fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_pomocniki-fryzjerskie"><span>Pomocniki fryzjerskie</span></a></li>
  <li class="tab has-icon"><a href="#tab_meble-48h"><span>Meble 48h</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With all respect, why to use display table method and not flexbox in 2019?

Comment: @ΑntonisPapadakis show me how you would get this behavior with flex (I tried before to play around min-content/max-content to mimimic the table algorithm) , is display:block, list-item or inline obsolete, ? why flex when we have grid ?  the thing is to pickup the display behavior you need ;)

Comment: With nav as display-flex you can write .nav > li {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    max-width: 70px;
}

Comment: @ΑntonisPapadakis but it will not shrink to fit the min-content example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwwdrgE 20% might be a good idea , .. but what about words longer  or bigger font-size ? ;) flex might be the obvious answser. or not, i would go on grid :) like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58940911/how-to-create-a-sidebar-with-2x3-grid-next-to-it/58941544#58941544  (the op thought about table at first) but again, you have here a width set for the grid element

Comment: Then you can play with flex-basis percentage :) , but I'm talking about methodology in general. I think table layout is an old school method nowadays. The most popular frameworks like Bootstrap, React native etc. use flexbox layout.

Comment: **popular** is the keyword, you said it ;)  `display:table` had never been popular,  it was mistaken with real table and hated for that,  and now flex or grid are seen as the ultimate display. I'm even surprised not to have been downvoted yet because of the  display:table.

Answer (score -2):

I would insert a `<br>` tag with a class attached that showed / hid the `<br>` depending on screen size.

Example:

HTML:

```
<p>FirstName<br class="line-break">LastName</p>
```

CSS:

```
/* Default for mobiles */
.line-break {
    display: block;
}

/* For tablets/desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .line-break {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way you're using html elements to edit the presentation of the site. It's nicer (and semantically correct) to leave the look and feel of the site to css, and use html strictly for the structure.

Comment: I take your point but strictly speaking, I am leaving the structure to `html`, I simply remove an element dependent on screen size - not any different to showing / hiding images on mobile / desktop. Also, the benefit of my method is that it is entirely flexible, even if the content changes (a different name is used etc) the logic remains.